Arrangement of a word within a word
I came across this question from a trial paper today that has me scratching my head.
The letters of the word IMPRESSION are rearranged such that the letters of the word
PRESS appear in order but not necessarily together.
One such arrangement is O P N R E I S M S I.
How many such arrangements are there?
The solution is
$$
\dfrac{10!}{5!2!}
$$
Without going through ALL the possibilities of arranging PRESS, I'm confused how the solution was obtained.
Thanks in advance.

Here is a method without stars and bars using successive placement (A search on this site will show its uses for different types of restrictions)

first place .P.R.E.S.S. which has $6$ gaps

One by one, place IMION, noting that each placement creates one more gap for placing the next letter, thus
$6.7.8.9.10/2!$ (for the two I's)$ =15,120$



Thanks true blue anil.  Can you explain what this means in your solution "noting that each placement creates one more gap for placing the next letter". If you place a letter (IMION) into a gap, how does create one more gap.  I'm missing something simple here.

$-P-R-E-S-S-$ has 6 gaps. If you place any other letter anywhere, e.g. $M$ between $P, R$ you get $-P-M-R-E-S-S-$ so now there are $7$ gaps to place the next letter, and so on.

Ahhh... I see.  Thank-you.  I do like the stars and bars approach.

I am also very fond of stars and bars, but it's good to have an armoury of tools for arrangements, you never know which will prove easier for a particular problem, and to me this approach seemed most clutter free for this problem.

Arrange the letters in PRESS in a line with gaps between them.  There are $6$ gaps.  Now order the letters in $IMION$ however you like. There are $\frac {5!}2$ ways to do that.  We now want to put the latter letters into the gaps.
Counting the ways to do that is a Stars and Bars Problem.  We are putting $5$ objects into $6$ bins with no constraints; equivalently, we want the sum of $6$ ordered non-negative integers to be $5$ and Stars and Bars gives us that count as $$\binom {5+6-1}{6-1}=\binom {10}5=\frac {10!}{5!\times 5!}$$
Thus the final answer is $$\frac {10!}{5!\times 5!}\times \frac {5!}2=\frac {10!}{5!\times 2}$$ as desired

Alternative approach:
Construe the problem to be a probability problem.
There are $~\dfrac{10!}{2! ~2!}~$ ways of permuting the letters in impression.
What is the probability that a random permutation will contain the letters press in the right order?
If the letters in the word press were all distinct, then the probability would be $~\dfrac{1}{5!},~$ because there would then be $~5!~$ ways of permuting the letters in the word, only one of which would be satisfactory.
Because the letters in the word press contain the double ss, there are only $~\dfrac{5!}{2!}~$ ways of permuting the letters in the word press, with only one of those ways being satisfactory.
Therefore, the final computation is
$$\frac{10!}{2! ~2!} \div \frac{5!}{2!} = \frac{10!}{5! ~2!}.$$

By symmetry, in $\frac{1}{\frac{5!}{2}}$ of the arrangements, the letters of the word PRESS will appear in that order within an arrangement.

@N.F.Taussig This corresponds with the point that I made in the paragraph beginning "Because the letters in the word press contain...".

The reason for my comment was that this is not a probability problem, which I should have made clear originally.  My apologies.

The word IMPRESSION has ten letters.  In addition to the letters of the word PRESS, it contains two Is, one M, one O, and one N.  Choose two of the ten positions for the Is.  Then there are eight ways to place the M, seven ways to place the O, and six ways to place the N.  That leaves five positions for the letters of the word PRESS.  There is only one way to arrange the letters of the word PRESS in the correct order in the remaining five positions.  Hence, the number of admissible arrangements is
$$\binom{10}{2} \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = \binom{10}{2} \cdot \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5!}{5!} = \binom{10}{2} \cdot \frac{8!}{5!} = \frac{10!}{2!8!} \cdot \frac{8!}{5!} = \frac{10!}{5!2!}$$

Consider the case of arranging all the letters of the word $PRESS$, that is ($5!$)/$2$. In this only PRESS occurs once, now, If I arrange the letters of $IMPRESSION$, the probability of appearance of $PRESS$ will be same as that of any other arrangement (for example $RSSEP$). So if we divide ($5!$)/$2$ by the total arrangements of letters of $IMPRESSION$ without any constraints we get our answer ($NOTE$- This method works for any word with whatsoever no. of letters)

Your answer duplicates the answer of user2661923.
